# C# % throws DivideByZeroException

Tags: c#, divide-by-zero

```
    public static List<int> getDenoms(long n)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                result.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int getHighestPrime(List<int> seq)
    {
        int currentHigh = 1;
        foreach (int number in seq)
        {
            List<int> temp = getDenoms(number);
            if (temp.Count == 1)
            {
                if (number > currentHigh)
                {
                    currentHigh = number;
                }
            }
        }
        return currentHigh;
    }
```

I have the current code going in C#. So, I have the two methods. In the getDenoms method, I assumed that the statement n%i would not throw any errors since i is greater than or equal to 1, but it does indeed throw that error.

I used the two methods in the following manner:

```
        Console.WriteLine(getHighestPrime(getDenoms(600851475143)));
```

Any insight on why the code is throwing that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `600851475143` is **too big** for an `int`!

Your looping variable `i` is an `int`, but you compare it to a `long`. `600851475143` is greater than `int.MaxValue`, so `i` eventually overflows and restarts at `int.MinValue`. Then it increases until it's `0` again and voilá:

> DivideByZeroException

To solve this change the type of your loop variable to `long`, too:

```
for (long i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: so would it work if I changed all the int values to be long?

Comment: @Jihan Yes, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

'i' is a int as 'n' is long, so in the for cicle 'i' overflows and after a while reaches the '0' value.

Fix:
for (long i = 1; i < n; i++)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this myself, but when I look at your code I see that your loop is using an *int* variable while your input is a *long*. The number that you are testing your function with, namely *600851475143*, is larger than what an 32-bit int can represent. Try changing your variable *i* to *long*.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the failure is that your value `600851475143` is larger than `int.MaxValue` to solve this problem go ahead and use `long` instead of `int`

Note that long.MaxValue is: 9223372036854775807

See code below

```
public static List<long> getDenoms(long n)
{
    List<long> result = new List<long>();
    for (long i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            result.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static long getHighestPrime(List<long> seq)
{
    int currentHigh = 1;
    foreach (long number in seq)
    {
        List<long> temp = getDenoms(number);
        if (temp.Count == 1)
        {
            if (number > currentHigh)
            {
                currentHigh = number;
            }
        }
    }
    return currentHigh;
}
```